# Is it possible to reload the react native app every time when the app is opened?

Tags: react-native, expo

I have an app built on Expo react.  In the app, I keep track of sales record for today, yesterday, etc. See the attached photo:
[image]

The problem is if today passed, and tomorrow I check the app, it still shows the same data as yesterday. If I log out my app, and log back in, it will show the data correctly. But how can I have my app to get refreshed every time when the app is opened without log out and log in?

Comment: use `componentDidMount` lifecycle, should be pretty straightforward

Comment: What do you mean by reset your app? Could you provide some code of your app? How are you managing the login? From where does your app fetch the data you show?

Comment: I used componentDidMount for my Home page, but it only be called when 1st time the page is loaded. After that, no matter how I switch between pages, when visiting Home page again, componentDidMount won't be called.

Comment: @RanderGabriel The data is fetched in componentDidMount inside Home page. I have a Drawer navigator to switch between different pages, say Profile page. When I switch to Profile page and then switch back to Home page, I didn't see componentDidMount getting called for Home page.

Comment: @RanderGabriel I should say to navigator to Home page and re-render the Home page every time the app is closed and then opened again

Comment: Thanks @Dhiraj. My previous componentDidMount doesn't have navigation.addListener. After the solution I posted below, I can have Home page re-rendered every time being visited again. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess the following code helps. I got it from a reddit post: https://www.reddit.com/r/reactnative/comments/9b8k4b/how_to_re_render_tab_screens_after_visiting_one/

```
componentDidMount () {
  const {navigation} = this.props;
  navigation.addListener ('willFocus', () =>
    // run function that updates the data on entering the screen
  );
}
```